# Remove with regex the end portion of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove from a string everything start with `/` char, so if I have

```
my_value/j/im<b*+èo[/h>e\ylo
```

I'd like to remove the string `/j/im<b*+èo[/h>e\ylo` and return only `my_value`.
I thought to use something with `str_replace` but I'm not a great regex programmer and I'm doing practise with php.

```
function clean_value ($value) {
    return preg_replace ("^(/.*?)$", "", $value);
}
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to use regex here. Use a combo of [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) instead:

```
$original = 'my_value/j/im<b*+èo[/h>e\ylo';

$removed = substr($original, 0, strpos($original, '/'));
```

The above will work if you can guarantee that the string will always have at least 1 `/` character in it. If you can't guarantee that or don't know, simply modify to:

```
$removed = (strpos($original, '/') === false)
             ? $original 
             : substr($original, 0, strpos($original, '/'));
```

Comment: If there is no `/`, `strpos` will return *false* and `substr` will return an empty string.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. preg is a waste, as is exploding into an array.

Comment: @Gumbo - I was just thinking that... updating

Comment: thank you, and thanks to all for the alternatives, they help me to understant what i can do

Answer (score 3):

The simplest things can be done without regex

```
$string = "my_value/j/im<b*+èo[/h>e\ylo";
$splitted = explode("/",$string,2);
echo  "$splitted[0]\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your regular expression. And `^/` requires the string to start with a `/`.

Try this instead:

```
preg_replace("~/.*~", "", $value)
```

This will remove anything from the first `/` up to the end.

Comment: Any suggestions how to remove from the _last_ `/` to the end?

Comment: @geotheory Try `/[^/]*$`.

Comment: Tx. Figured out a non-regex solution too: `str.split("/").slice(0, str.split("/").length-1).join('/').concat("/")`

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the starting caret from your regexp, and you can use a greedy match to get the rest of the string:

```
function clean_value ($value) {
    return preg_replace ("/\/.*/", "", $value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the delimiters too... :S fixed.